# Lightning winter 17 list view inline edit example?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning, lightning-apps

I am trying to incorporate inline editing for list view. Earlier, I did some research with open source solutions based on jquery based grids. But found that Salesforce has introduced beta release of "Optimize Clicks and Time by Editing Inline (Beta)" into winter'17 release.

Question is has anyone implemented this feature? i am trying to find example solution or good documentation on how to implement this feature.

[image]